# Retrieve an array of a property from an array of objects

Tags: c#, linq

Assume the following class:

```
class Person
{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

Lets say that I have a list or an array of Person object.  Is there a way using LINQ to retrieve FirstName property from all the array elements and return an array of string.  I have a feeling that I have seen something like that before.

Hope that the question makes sense.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sure, very easily:

```
Person[] people = ...;
string[] names = people.Select(x => x.FirstName).ToArray();
```

Unless you really *need* the result to be an array though, I'd consider using `ToList()` instead of `ToArray()`, and potentially just leaving it as a lazily-evaluated `IEnumerable<string>` (i.e. *just* call `Select`). It depends what you're going to do with the results.

Answer (score 8):

If you have an *array*, then personally, I'd use:

```
Person[] people = ...
string[] names = Array.ConvertAll(people, person => person.FirstName);
```

here; it avoids a few reallocations, and works on more versions of .NET. Likewise:

```
List<Person> people = ...
List<string> names = people.ConvertAll(person => person.FirstName);
```

LINQ will *work*, but isn't actually *required* here.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating, but personally I'd probably still use LINQ - as it's arguably more idiomatic these days, and will be more flexible in the face of either changing requirements or changing input type. I'd use `Array.ConvertAll` in performance-sensitive code, or using .NET 2.0 of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Person()
    {
        FirstName = "Brandon",
        LastName = "Zeider"
    });
people.Add(new Person()
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe"
});

var firstNameArray = people.Select(p => p.FirstName).ToArray();
```

Comment: You can make your setup code considerably simpler using object and collection initializers :)

Comment: You are of course right Jon (aren't you always haha). If my browser had refreshed I would have saw that you and Marc had already answered and I wouldn't have bothered. :)